# Can Sails.js application be run in Apache

Tags: apache, node.js, sails.js

Can Sails.js based application be run in Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't run Javascript on Apache. But you can run Javascript on Node.js and proxy pass your request from Apache to Node.js. You can read more about proxy pass, Apache and Node.js [here](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache)

Comment: Great link- I'd add that you only need to do something like this if you have Apache hosting other sites on the same server.

Comment: Has a broken link in answer. Ends with server not reachable.